# SharkX6 Flight Controller USB data connection cable

Tags: usb, data, line

I have a SharkX6 flight controller (FC) that I am using in a quadcopter that I am building. The flight controller came with a broken (the fried IC is to the left of the '100' component) power distribution board (see attached image). This board besides providing +5V to the FC (via a voltage regulator circuit) and power to the ESCs, also provides a USB circuit for connecting the flight controller to the PC via a MicroUSB port. The USB circuit in the power distribution board takes 4 USB lines (VCC/5V, DATA+, DATA- and GND) and outputs two lines marked U+ and U- that go to the FC USB pins. The USB circuit is shown with the blue arrow in the picture. On the right of the board BLACK is VCC, WHITE is D+, RED is D- and ORANGE is GND.

The power distribution board picture is here: [image]

Using a (borrowed) working power distribution board, when connected to the PC I verified that my FC is correctly recognized by the PC, so the FC USB connection port works. The problem I have is that I have to somehow create a cable or circuit to replicate this function because the power distribution board is not available for sale and I would like to be able to connect my FC to my computer and change it's parameters.

My question is: is there some ready-made or easy to understand and build circuit that would allow me to connect the FC to the PC? I have tried pulling up the D+ line to 3.33V by using the VCC line through a voltage divider without success; the computer does recognize that a USB device is connected but it fails with an unknown descriptor and I get the familiar Windows message for malfunctioning device.

Answer (score 1):

Nice picture with enough detail to see useful things.

Looks like the USB data lines are just jumpered (0-ohm resistors) to the U+ U- lines - have you tried that? (along with supplying power as needed) - to be clear don't "pull the data line" anywhere - let the USB device (flight controller) you are connecting to do that. USB power should not be very much (if at all) involved here since there's a power supply already going on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, "jumpering" D+ D- with U+ and U- respectively was the first thing I did without success (the computer does not detect the USB device at all).Using a voltometer, I measured U+ and U- from the working power board and it is +3.74V. The broken board performs the same but the Windows "unrecognized/malfunctioning" message appears.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say if +5V is working on the board. I have a similar problem with a quad I bought that didn't work. In my case, the 100 component was separated from the board, and wouldn't supply power. I bridged it back, and the quad woke up. But its USB doesn't work. Mine is from a Flying 3D X8, which is similar, but components are in different locations.

Comment: In my case the problem relies with the step-down module - the 8-pin IC to the left of the '100' component - which is damaged. By supplying 5V - via an external step-down module - to the DC input lines, the USB connection worked.